# Create a figure from other figures pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

In a Jupyter notebook I create a series of plots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def getPlot(model, title, subtitle=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.imshow(model) 
    ax.axis('off')
    if subtitle:
        fig.suptitle(subtitle)
        title+="\n"
    fig.gca().set(title=title)
    return fig
```

(the model is an array)

Then:

```
plt01 = getPlot(model=..., title=..., subtitle=...)
```

...

```
plt02 = getPlot(model=..., title=..., subtitle=...)
```

Later, I'd like to show all the plots as single image.

I have searched and searched, and now I know well how to create a multi-figure figure by adding the data as the figure is created, but not adding existing figures.

For example, the official [Figure subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html) has multiple examples but none of them uses a subfigure that's created before the final figure is created.

I imagined that something like the following would work, but I only get the string `<Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>`.

```py
fig = plt.figure()
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=2, wspace=0.07)
subfigs[0] = plt01
subfigs[1] = plt02
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I've changed my code to capture the data (instead of plots) at given points and then at the end:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 2))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=1, ncols=4, wspace=0.07)

draw(subfigs[0],model= data0)
draw(subfigs[1],model= data1)
draw(subfigs[2],model= data2)
draw(subfigs[3],model= data3)
```

To support this I changed the drawing code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def getFig(model):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
    draw(fig, model)
    return fig

def draw(fig, model):
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    drawAx(ax, model)

def drawAx(ax, model):    
    ax.imshow(model.data) 
    ax.axis('off')
    title = model.name
    if model.extra:
        title += "\n"+model.extra
    ax.set_title(title)
```

where `model` is a named tuple now.

Comment: This is fine.  But why not just use subplots instead of subfigure?

Comment: Using figures and not plots, just comes from my ignorance. Are plots preferred?